# Complex Analysis:Show that $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that there is $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(z)=e^{i\theta}z^{a}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytical on ann $A(0;r,R)$ and suppose there is $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(z)|=|z|^{a}$, $\forall z \in A$. Show that $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that there is $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(z)=e^{i\theta}z^{a}$.

I have the impression that using Schwarz's lemma forms $ f(z)=e^{i\theta}z^{a} $, but I cannot develop it. I can't think of results that prove  $  a \in \mathbb{Z} $. Could you help me with ideas?

Comment: One approach would be to write out the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form.

Comment: Try using the Open Mapping Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I use $r$ for $\vert z\vert$, so I will change the domain to $A(0;R_1,R_2)$)

Write $f(re^{i\phi})=R(r,\phi)e^{i\psi(r,\phi)}$. By assumption $R(r,\phi)=r^a$. Thus the Cauchy-Riemann equations give us \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\phi}(r,\phi)&=a\\
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial r}(r,\phi)&=0\\
\end{align*}
Hence $\psi(r,\phi)=a\phi+\theta$ for some constant $\theta\in\Bbb R$. We then get for $z=re^{i\phi}$: $$f(z)=f(re^{i\phi})=r^ae^{i(a\phi+\theta)}=e^{i\theta}z^a$$ in $A(0,R_1,R_2)\setminus\{x\in \Bbb R\mid R_1<x<R_2\}$. We know that $f$ is actually defined on the whole annulus $A(0;R_1,R_2)$ which is not possible if $a\notin\Bbb Z$.
**Edit:** The Cauchy-Riemann equations for the function in polar coordinates as above are:\begin{align*}
r\frac{\partial R}{\partial r}&=R\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\phi}\\
\frac{\partial R}{\partial \phi}&=-rR\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\phi}
\end{align*}
Now plug in $R(r,\phi)=r^a$.

Comment: why can we write $f(re^{i\phi}) = R(r,\phi)e^{i\psi(r, \phi)}$ ?

Comment: That is the polar form of complex numbers which is (locally) uniquely determined

Comment: I can't understand how Cauchy Riemann equations were used

Comment: lastly, I didn't understand why $ a\notin \mathbb{Z} $ on the last line.

Comment: Because for $a\notin\Bbb Z$ it is not possible to extend $z^a$ analytically on the whole of $A(0;R_1,R_2)$. To see this choose the branch of the logarithm defined by $\ln(e^{i\phi})=i\phi$ for $\phi\in (0,2\pi)$. If we take any $r\in(R_1,R_2)$ then the limit of $z^a$ as $z\to r$ from above (i.e. with positive imaginary part) is $r^a$. The limit from below will be $r^ae^{i2\pi a}$. Now $e^{2\pi ai}$ is $1$ iff $a\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: to finish, could you explain to me who is \psi? how is this function definition?

Comment: That is the argument of $f(z)$, i.e. a real number $x$ with $f(z)=\vert z\vert e^{ix}$. This is only modulo $2\pi$ uniquely determined. If we fix the the argument at a point $z$ then the function $\psi$ is uniquely determined in a neighborhood of $z$ and we can use the reasoning in the answer to conclude $f(z)=z^a$ in that neighborhood and then conclude via identity theorem.

Comment: All in all, the solution by @zhw. is definitely more elegant and easier, you should rather accept his answer.

Comment: I got a little lost the fact that $f(z)=z^{a}e^{i\theta}$ in $A(0,R_1 ,R_2) \setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R} : R_1< x < R_2\}$. could you clarify? please

Comment: If you have a complex number $z$ in polar form, i.e. $z=re^{i\phi}$ for some fixed branch of the logarithm, then $z^a=r^ae^{ia\phi}$ (in that branch). So here we have $$r^ae^{i(a\phi+\theta)}=r^ae^{ia\phi+i\theta}=r^ae^{ia\phi}e^{i\theta}=z^ae^{i\theta}$$

Comment: why in $ A(0, R_1, R_2) \setminus \{ x \in \mathbb {R}: R_1 <x <R_2 \} $?

Comment: Because a branch of the logarithm cannot be defined on the whole of the annulus, you need a branch cut, i.e. you take out a ray. In this case I took out the part on the positive real axis. In this way there is a unique way of writing $z=re^{i\phi}$ (after fixing one branch of the logarithm), so writing $f(re^{i\phi})$ as a function of $r,\phi$ is actually well-defined

Answer (score 2):

The principal branch of $g(z)=z^a$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0].$ We then have both $f,g$ holomorphic in $U=A(r,R)\setminus (-\infty,0],$ an open connected set. Note both $f,g$ are nonzero in $U.$ Thus in $U$ we have $f/g$ holomorphic, with $|f/g|=1.$ It follows that $(f/g)(U)$ is not open. By the open mapping theorem, $f/g = C$ in $U,$ where $C$ is a constant of modulus $1.$ Therefore $f(z)/C = z^a$ in $U.$ It follows that $z^a$ extends to be holomorphic in $A(r,R).$ But we know for that to happen $a$ must be an integer.